# What is a "woggy dago"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, offensive-language

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the origin of the word “wog”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24768/what-is-the-origin-of-the-word-wog)

I was listening to a song the other day, and it featured the words "woggy dago".

Now I did manage to find out what *dago* means, but I'm still not clear about *woggy*.
It isn't in the dictionary, and while I could find it on the net, none of the apparent meanings fit the context in the song.

I also googled for "woggy dago", but then nothing turns up, except for the lyrics to said song!

So, what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Woggy is the adjective formed from *wog*, an offensive term for non-white people which is commonly believed to be derived from *golliwog*.

In Australian slang, *wog* means "a foreigner or immigrant, especially one from southern Europe," which accords with *dago,* "a Spanish, Portuguese, or Italian-speaking person."

[ODO on *wog*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/wog), [*golliwog*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/golliwog) and [*dago*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dago?q=dago). All are noted as offensive.

Comment: [Wog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wog) has a different meaning in Australia.and apparently elsewhere in the world as well. FWIW, I also see that both _wog_ and [dago](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dago) have a naval sense in common.

Comment: You might also add that this is strictly a BrE word. And that *dago* is a term for someone of Spanish, Italian, or Portuguese extraction (from Sp. *diego*).

Comment: Added. The naval sense of both words is interesting, but unlikely to be relevant to the question.

Comment: Non-white eh? Oh well.

Comment: I'm unsure of what the nature of these words are and unsure what would be the most appropriate etymological explanation; but, as far as I concern and for what is worth, more details on naval sense of both words, or at least of the word "wog", would have been important  for full comprehension of the answer, especially in this delicate context.

Comment: @coleopterist: what is this 'different' meaning? and what is this naval meaning?

Comment: @Mitch The answer initially didn't include the Aussie slang and naval should have been maritime: "Pollywog, a maritime term for someone who has not crossed the equator" | "Usually a sailor or deckhand. "diego" is the Portuguese nickname for any deckhand and "jack" is the British equivalent".